# What are the sufficient condition for common geometry shapes like rectangle, square, circle, triangle? And how to check it programmatically?

Tags: geometry

For example, given 4 points it is hard (for me atleast) to check if they form a rectangle because it is not easy to write code for proving 90 degrees between 2 sides.

How would you do it? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Question is too general. It is not hard to check for rectangle using dot (scalar) product (with proper vertex ordering)

Comment: Mind sharing an example? Say, given 4 points how do I check if it is a rect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given: 4 points `a,b,c,d`
Needed: check if they form a rectangle

Find coordinate differences like this:

```
BAx = B.x - A.x
```

Check whether dot products for three subsequent edges are zero (true perpendicular vectors):

```
function IsPerp(A,B,C,D) 
   return ((BAx * CBx + BAy * CBy == 0) && 
          (CBx * DCx + CBy * DCy == 0) && 
          (DCx * ADx + DCy * ADy == 0))
```

But note that vertices might be wrong ordered, so we check three variants (it is simpler than order them well) to avoid zigzag-like orders:

```
IsRectangle = IsPerp(a,b,c,d) || IsPerp(a,b,d,c) || IsPerp(a,d,b,c)
```